# why C# project run in Visual Studio under source code directory is faster than invoke it's exe file in another directory

Tags: c#, release

I write a project, traverse all files(about 3000 files) under a directory and read all these file content into memory.

When I press F5 run the project in Visual studio, it finished within 1 minutes. B

But when I copy the \bin\Debug\projectName.exe to another folder, then open cmd window, and invoke the projectName.exe use the same arguments, it finished more than 10 minutes.

Why the second way cost so much time, any one who can help me? thanks.

Comment: Was the working directory the same for both runs?

Comment: It could happen if the second folder contains much more files then the first or much bigger 'tree' of directories. Check it.

Comment: The 2 projects are under 2 different directory, but they hander the same input arguments, that mean they use the same directory as input argument, and the directory contains too much folders and files, more than 3000 files in total.

Comment: Have you tried profiling your program, to see where it spends all of it's time in each scenario?

Comment: Maybe in VS uses Release configuration, not Debug?

Comment: I was used the debug